# Chrome registering going to homepage as going back

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome

I have weird problem with Wordpress. I've made POST script which redirect user from single.php to index.php.
The problem is that Chrome recognizes going to index.php as going 'Back' literally, so it doesn't refresh page or read POST parameters.
However, this works perfectly in Mozilla or Edge.

Any tips on how to fix this annoying behavior of Chrome?

```
  <form method="post" id="back-form" action="localhost/wordpress/">;    
    <input type="hidden" name="no" id="no" value="<?php echo $no; ?>">    
    <input type="submit" id="header-back" value=""> 
  </form>
```

Comment: That sounds interesting.  Can you post the portion of your code which handles the redirect please?

Comment: Code posted in post.

Answer (score 1):

Add something to let the browser know you are not requesting a page that it can give you from cache:

```
<form method="post" id="back-form" action="localhost/wordpress/?x=<?php echo uniquid(); ?>">;    
  <input type="hidden" name="no" id="no" value="<?php echo $no; ?>">    
  <input type="submit" id="header-back" value=""> 
</form>
```

Alternatively, you can use a Wordpress plugin or personal code to send headers that immediately expire the cache of the page.

Comment: I already tried using GET instead of POST. Even if I hardcode link in href attribute, Chrome thinks I'm going back. I also tried disabling browser cache, unfortunately no success.

Comment: i wasn't suggesting using GET. you just need to make the url unique. leave the form action as POST. have you looked into sending no-cache headers in Wordpress?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean. Any url consisting 'localhost/wordpress/?x={whatever}' will be threated as 'Back'.

Comment: I tried disabling cache both with PHP headers and meta tags. No success.